# Is it possible to get information about an object from a Geofence?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-geofence

I wondered if I could get some help, I am creating an application that uses points objects to create routes, I have certain points on each route that act as 'waypoints' and with that I have it so each of these points it tied to a geofence.

So far I can trigger the geofence event etc as it is crossed, but I would like to (if possible) get information about the actual 'Point' such as its description etc to display in another activity, that the geofence is meant to represent, I am unsure how I can achieve this, I can only seem to get the ID of the geofence, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Object TAG = "Error";
    NotifactionHelper notifactionHelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        notifactionHelper = new NotifactionHelper(context);

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.d("geoferror", "onReceive: Geofence even has error..");
        }

        List<Geofence> triggeredGeofenceList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        for (Geofence geofence : triggeredGeofenceList) {
            Log.d("GEOF", "onReceive: "+geofence.getRequestId());
        }

        Location triggerLocation = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        double lat = triggerLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon = triggerLocation.getLongitude();

        
        int transitionType = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        switch (transitionType) {

            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Entered Geofence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("GEOF", "onReceive: "+geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition());
                notifactionHelper.sendNotification("A Waypoint is Nearby!", "Open the Application to find out more", RouteActivity.class);
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Dwelling inside of Geofence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Exited Geofence area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;



        }

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        Intent i = new Intent("TESTER");
        i.putExtra("lat", lat);
        i.putExtra("lon", lon);
        i.putExtras(b);
        
        context.sendBroadcast(i);


    }

}
```

Also my geofence Method, it takes the Lat & Lng from each point in the list to create the geoFence

```
private void addGeoFence(LatLng latLng, float radius) {

        List<Geofence> geofence = geoFenceHelper.getGeoFence(GEOFENCE_ID, latLng, radius,
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);

        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = geoFenceHelper.getGeoFencingRequest(geofence);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = geoFenceHelper.getPendingIntent();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingIntent)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

And also my geofenceHelper class

```
public class GeoFenceHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    private static final java.util.UUID UUID = null;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    /** Constructor
     *
     * @param base
     */
    public GeoFenceHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public GeofencingRequest getGeoFencingRequest(List<Geofence> geofence) {

        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .addGeofences(geofence)
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .build();

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ID
     * @param latLng
     * @param radius
     * @param transitionTypes
     * @return
     */
    public List <Geofence> getGeoFence (String ID, LatLng latLng, float radius, int transitionTypes) {

        List<Geofence> returnGeoFenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        returnGeoFenceList.add(
                new Geofence.Builder()
                        .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                        .setRequestId(id)
                        .setTransitionTypes(transitionTypes)
                        .setLoiteringDelay(2000)
                        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        .build());

        return returnGeoFenceList;

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {

        if(pendingIntent != null) {
            return  pendingIntent;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,2607, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: `such as its description etc` Please come to the 'point'. What exactly? Be precise!

Comment: Apologies, each Point is an object that contains its, LatLng, a String description for the point and a enum PointType, when the geofence is triggered I would like my activity to show me more about the point that I have reached, such as its description and LatLng in another activity.

Comment: You have not even explained what you mean with 'description'. Be it that you explained the 'etc'.

Comment: Apologies once again.. the 'description' is an instance variable of the Point object, it can be used to add a description with more information about the specific Point.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the data about the locationin a db, including the id of the point.  Look up the data by the id which is passed to you.  The Geofence itself shouldn't hold this data, but it should be tied to the data relationally.

Comment: Thank you Gabe, at the moment I am storing the information of each route in Firestore, each point is part of a List of type Point within each route, although I have not given each point a unique id